# how to configure InAppBrowser on phonegap for Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

how to configure InAppBrowser on phonegap for Blackberry. Is there any alternative plugin available for blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try out the ChildBrowser plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/ChildBrowser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BB10 and developing with WebWorks then you don't need any phonegap plugins. BB10 and WebWorks has a built in childbrowser. You can just open it with `window.open`.